# Da cosa dipende l'uso del suffisso di appartenenza -ese rispetto a -ita (e altri) nei demotici?

Tags: etymology, suffix

Ad esempio:

genovese, ma moscovita
francese, ma yemenita
congolese, ma kenyota (o keniota)

Sono al corrente del fatto che -ita sia usato principalmente per l'appartenenza a gruppi religiosi, ma per quanto riguarda l'appartenenza politica/geografica non trovo un pattern soddisfacente e i risultati sembrano piuttosto casuali. In molti casi non si può neanche sostenere che la ragione sia unicamente fonetica, perché parole come *moscovese o *yemenese, da nativo, mi sembrerebbero perfettamente accettabili dal punto di vista eufonico e fonotattico.

C'è una ragione per cui un certo suffisso è stato usato sugli altri per determinati paesi?

Comment: Ti interessano solo questi due suffissi? Pensandoci qualche minuto trovo che negli aggettivi e nomi relativi a città a nazioni sia più la varietà che l'omogeneità: -ano (che è sicuramente uno dei più fertili: italiano, romano, napoletano, reggiano, marchigiano, messicano, egiziano, israeliano, indiano...), -ino (fiorentino, parigino, reggino, marocchino...), suffissi zero (svizzero, bulgaro, lombardo...), -asco (bergamasco, comasco, monegasco, ) -aco (austriaco, peloponnesiaco...), oltre a casi più singolari come urbinate e tifernate.

Comment: C'è qualcosa qui: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/etnici_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano) , ma temo che sia difficile dire qualcosa di più organico di motivi storici legati, caso per caso, alla singola città o nazione.

Comment: Giusto per confronto: i capoluoghi di provincia della mia regione danno *bellunese*, *padovano*, *trevisano* (o, versione colta, *trevigiano*), *rodigino* (o *rovigotto*, ma meglio non usarlo), *veneziano*, *veronese*, *vicentino*. Sembra chiaro che la sillaba finale con *n* impedisca il suffisso *-ano*. Un dizionario fa risalire *moscovita* al XVI secolo.

Comment: No @DaG, mi interessa in generale, quelli sono i due suffissi che mi hanno principalmente incuriosito inizialmente.  
È possibile che almeno parte della ragione sia il periodo storico in cui il termine è nato? Magari durante un periodo x si tendeva di più verso un certo suffisso e in uno y verso un altro.